# Finding the number of different surjective representation on 2 sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Having two sets

```
X = { 1 ,2 ,3 }
Y = { a, b }
```

What is the number of different surjective representation?

Surjective represenation means that every element from Y has to have atleast one element from X e.g

$\forall y\exists x:f(x) = y$

But can two elements from Y have same corrsesponding element in X? How could we use combinatorics to find the answer to find number of surjective representations?

`a` can have `({1}, {1,2} , {1,2,3}` as correspondive pattern from set X.
`b` is the same. By the logic , the order is not important , and elements cannot be repeated so is this typical user of combination where n = 2 and n = 3?which means answer should be
$\frac{3!}{(3-2)!*2!} * \frac{3!}{(3-2)!*2!}$
which is 9?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a$, you can choose one  from$\;3\;$ elements, which gives $\binom{3}{1}$ possibilities.

for $b$, you choose one  from $3-1=2$ since it can't take an element already taken by $a$ cause it is a surjection.

the number of surjections is

$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}=6$$

Comment: We have a selftest online where we can practise for upcoming exams , i wrote 9 as answer to this question and it was wrong

Comment: I cannot test it now , cuz seltest are self generated . Would you mind to epxlain why b can choose only from 2 ?

Comment: Yes , now it is , thanks!